# mobile game monetization sdk

Tags: windows-mobile, symbian

I developed a game for Windows Mobile. I am looking for a platform/SDK such that it will allow me sell extra levels and other in game items. There are SDKs for adding ads to the game (e.g. [admob](http://www.admob.com/)) but that is not what I am interested in. Basically I need a platform that will handle purchases for me. And they provide APIs that would allow me to direct user to appropriate payment application/website. Also I should be able to check what user have paid for already. Do you know any such platform that will work for Windows Mobile or Symbian? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a company called [PlaySpan](http://corp.playspan.com/) which does provide such functionality. I have no experience with them though.

Comment: Hi tomlog, thanks for the answer. They seem to do what I asked for. But there is not much information on their web site. They do not even mentioned the platforms they supported. I am not sure they support mobile at all. Anyway, I will try to figure it out.

Comment: It shouldn't really matter if they support mobile or not. You probably would setup a web service on your end that acts as a middle man between the mobile app and the content payment platform. Their website does mention they uses web services, so presumably they have some sort of API available to developers.